# Rounding the result of division in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I'm performing the following operation in Javascript:

> 0.0030 / 0.031

How can I round the result to an arbitrary number of places? What's the maximum number that a `var` will hold?

Comment: e is closer to w than o to n on most keyboards

Comment: This is now a valid question.

Answer (score 20):

Modern browsers should support a method called `toFixed()`.  Here's [an example taken from the web](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html):

```
// Example: toFixed(2) when the number has no decimal places
// It will add trailing zeros
var num = 10;
var result = num.toFixed(2); // result will equal 10.00

// Example: toFixed(3) when the number has decimal places
// It will round to the thousandths place
num = 930.9805;
result = num.toFixed(3); // result will equal 930.981
```

`toPrecision()` might also be useful for you, there is another excellent example on that page.

---

For older browsers, you can achieve it manually using `Math.round`.  `Math.round()` will round to the nearest integer.  In order to achieve decimal precision, you need to manipulate your numbers a bit:

1. Multiply the original number by 10^x
   (10 to the power of x), where x is
   the number of decimal places you
   want.

   - Apply Math.round()
   - Divide by 10^x

So to round 5.11111111 to three decimal places, you would do this:

```
var result=Math.round(5.111111*1000)/1000  //returns 5.111
```

Comment: Don't forget that JScript's `toFixed` implementation is rather deficient - http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#formatNumber

Answer (score 2):

The largest positive finite value of the number type is approximately **1.7976931348623157 * 10<sup>308</sup>**. ECMAScript-262 3rd ed. also defines `Number.MAX_VALUE` which holds that value.

Answer (score 1):

To answer Jag's questions:

1. Use the toFixed() method. Beware; it returns a string, not a number.
2. Fifteen, maybe sixteen. If you try to get more, the extra digits will be either zeros or garbage. Try formatting something like 1/3 to see what I mean.